# Windows Username in WCF 4 Rest

Tags: wcf, authentication, wcf-rest

I'm having difficulty with Windows authentication in a WCF REST app.

Using VS2010, I chose New Project>WCF REST Service Application.

I modified the web.config to assure windows authentication and deny anonymous users.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

  </system.web>
```

I altered Service1.cs to return the username in the response:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "",
    RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public List<SampleItem> GetCollection()
{
    // TODO: Replace the current implementation to return a collection of SampleItem instances
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
    string fullID = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name;

    return new List<SampleItem>() { new SampleItem() { Id = 1, StringValue = "Hello " + fullID } };
}
```

I test it successfully running on local machine, then I publish it to IIS7 on Windows Server 2008.  In IIS Manager, I enable Windows Authentication on the app and disable all other authentication types. 
I give it its own Application Pool with integrated managed pipeline mode.

I can successfully see it in windows explorer running on the Win2008 machine (http://localhost/JobManager/Service1/)

Using IE 7 from another machine, however, it prompts me twice for username/password, I fill it in twice but get a 401 error the second time. (Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by changing the identity used by the app pool to one that has access to directory services.